# Windows scripting, setting the advanced properties of network connections

Tags: powershell, wsh

Has anyone got a powershell script or similiar for setting the "dns suffix for this connection" part in the advanced properties of a particular network connection?

thanks

Comment: Nearly there:

gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter  -filter "netconnectionid='Local Area Connection'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name SetDNSDomain -ArgumentList @('contoso.com')

results in:

Comment: Invoke-WmiMethod : This method is not implemented in any class
At D:\Documents and Settings\tony\Desktop\dns.ps1:1 char:96
+ gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter  -filter "netconnectionid='Local Area Connection'"
| Invoke-WmiMethod <<<<  -Name SetDNSDomain -ArgumentList @('contoso.com')
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod

Answer (score 1):

Try this (run PowerShell as admin):

```
    Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Description='interface description'" | 
Invoke-WmiMethod -Name SetDNSDomain -ArgumentList @('contoso.com')
```